# How to render a pure component dynamically in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, carousel, react-component

I'm trying to render some pure components / a component which are basically RE charts in a carousel. So far I have implemented with images, but when I'm passing pure component / a component it is not showing anything.

I have created a sandbox which is having all the code which I have written so far with all the details SCSS, Re chart component and a main component. Please have a look and let me know what I'm missing or is there any other way where I can render components in a carousel.

> [Codesandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-night-zwvg1)

Comment: I don't see any pure components in the sandbox you linked. So i'm not sure what part of that codebase you're asking about.

Comment: your scss is causing the issue, you can easily fix it by inspecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-frost-8p3m3)

The problem is that you need to define exactly the width and height of the svg also at its "containers", meaning that `style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}` needs to be applied to `li` and `ul` too.

Also i changed a little bit the transform slide width.